# inception model folder not available when installing with pip

Tags: tensorflow

The github source for tensorflow contains a folder called inception under models. 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception/inception

However, there is no such folder when I install using pip

The pip installation resides at:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/
```

Is this discrepancy because of the version I am using when installing with with pip? I used this link TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

when installing using pip. Is this correct?

Pleasec check

Comment: Looks like models (along with several other related projects such as magenta  and serving) are not part of tensorflow release; you can download/check out it separately though. https://github.com/tensorflow

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the tip.